# Accels file for Nautilus on Fedora 23

Tags: fedora, gnome, nautilus, fedora-23

I just recently installed Fedora 23 on my machine, and still have my f20 install on my machine. When trying to 'fix' Nautilus so that backspace goes back, I noticed that there is no longer an accels file under `~/.config/nautilus/` so I tried adding my old one, but have had no luck.

I've tried to find an `accels` file somewhere else on the machine, but to no avail. Does anyone know if they've changed the way that you can alter nautilus behaviour in the recent Gnome update?

FYI: Gnome Nautilus 3.18.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's the answer:

The accels file no longer works.
It was implemented for GtkAction but since nautilus was ported to GAction, the old implementation no longer works.

Comment: For user scripts, there is a new solution, see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/680016/keyboard-shortcut-for-open-terminal-nautilus-3-16/